# How do I configure my RDS properly to my Flask app deployed on Elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

So I have created a flask app that is deployed using Elastic beanstalk. I have configured a MySQL RDS database, database to the flask app in the same environment. The database seems to be connected and working fine, but after a while the connection is lost, and I get 500 Server overloaded error. This is happening because the database and the app is disconnected. I tried to force a connection using @before_first_request decorator but it doesn't seem to work. Whenever I restart my application server that's when the database and app connection is working fine. I am using SQLAlchemy as my ORM. I have no issues connecting MySQL workbench locally though. Is this because I am using the Free tier ?
This is my app.py code :

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY']= 'anandandkaustubh'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://admin:Password@petbiotech-site.czufb7vlwyub.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ebdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'pool_recycle': 1800,  # 30 minutes
    'connect_args': {'connect_timeout': 30}
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap4')

@before_first_request
def connect_to_database():
    db.engine.connect()
```

These are my security groups for RDS :
[RDS Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYMsG.png)

I don't know if should set up an EC2 connection to my RDS database ? How do I go around with this ? Please help me out.